# Can't access web container from outside (Windows Docker-Desktop)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i'm using Docker-Desktop on Windows and i'm trying to get running 3 containers inside docker-desktop.
After few research and test, i get the 3 container running [WEB - API - DB], everything seems to compile/run without issue in the logs but i'can't access my web container from outside.

Here's my dockerfile and docker-compose, what did i miss or get wrong ?

[WEB] dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

#EXPOSE 4200 (the issue is the same with or without this line)

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

[API] dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.1-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app

#EXPOSE 2022 (the issue is the same with or without this line)

CMD ["java", "-jar", "test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  ### FRONTEND ###
  web:
    container_name: wallet-web
    restart: always
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "80:4200"
    depends_on:
      - "api"
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.12
    #networks:
    #  - "api"
    #  - "web"

  ### BACKEND ###
  api:
    container_name: wallet-api
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "2022:2022"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11
    #networks:
    #  - "api"
    #  - "web"

  ### DATABASE ###
  db:
    container_name: wallet-db
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10
    #networks:
    #  - "api"
    #  - "web"
networks:
  customnetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.20.0.1
#  api:
#  web:
```

Listening on:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFTPz.png)

I found several issue similar to mine but the solution didn't worked for me.

Comment: What does your web application listen to?
127.0.0.1:4200? 0.0.0.0:4200?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux 
it's listening on 0.0.0.0:4200

Comment: Do you have the same problem inside the container?

Comment: @xirehat
What do you mean by inside the container ?
Log and ping other container ?

Comment: What I mean is that you enter the container (`docker compose exec web bash`) and make a request to the same port, for example with the curl command `curl localhost:4200`

Comment: @xirehat when i do the command i get the content of the index.html page

Comment: What do you mean by "outside"?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux by outside i mean in the browser, i can't access the index.html, like if the port was not exposed

Comment: could you try in your terminal with curl -vvv ?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux inside the app container with the command `curl localhost -vvv` i get the message `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`, if use the command `curl localhost:4200 -vvv` i get the content of the index.html page

Comment: if you want to use 80. You should map this port in docker-compose yaml file. 80:4200

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux     ports mapped in docker-compose to `80:4200` i got the same message `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: Are you sure 80 is available?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the browsers development console, if there comes any error. Your docker-compose seems not to have any issue.

How ever lets try to debug it:

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                    NAMES
6245eaffd67e   nginx             "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:4200->80/tcp     test-api-1
```

copy the container id then execute:

```
 docker exec -it 6245eaffd67e  bin/bash
```

Now you are inside the container. Instead of the id you can use also the containers name.

```
curl http://localhost:80
```

Note: in my case here i just create a container from an nginx image.
In your case use the port where your app is running. Control it in your code if you arent sure. A lot of Javascript-frameworks start default on 3000.

If you get an error: curl command not found, install it in your image:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim
USER root # to install dependencies you need sudo permissions su we tell the image that it is root
RUN apt update -y && apt install curl -y
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

#EXPOSE 4200 (the issue is the same with or without this line)
USER node # we dont want to execute the image as root so we put user node (this user is defined in the  node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim image)
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Now the curl should work (if it doesnt already).

The same should work from your host.
Here is an important thing:

The localhost, always refers to the fisical computer, or the container itselfs where you are refering. Every container and your PC have localhost and they are not the same.
In the docker-compose you just map the port host/container, so your PC (host) where docker is running can access the docker network from the host on the host port you defined, inside the port of the container.

If you cant still access from your host, try to change the host ports 2022, 4200 ecc. Could be possible that something conflicts on your Windows machine.

It happens sometimes that the docker networks can create some conflicts.
Execute a docker-compose down, so it should be delete and recreated.

Still not working?

Reset docker-desktop to factory settings, control if you have last version (this is always better).

If all this doesnt help, let me know so we can debugg further.

For the sake of clarity i post you here the docker-compose which i used to check. I just used nginx to test the ports as i dont have your images.

````
version: "3.8"

services:
  ### FRONTEND ###
  web:
    restart: always
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    depends_on:
      - "api"
    networks:
      - "web"

  ### BACKEND ###
  api:
    restart: always
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "2022:80"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    networks:
      - "api"
      - "web"

  ### DATABASE ###
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    networks:
      - "api"
networks:
  api:
  web:
```

Update:

You can log what happens in the conatiner like so:

```
docker logs containerid/name
```

If you are using Visualcode there is excellent extension for docker build also by Microsoft:
Just search docker in the extensions. Has something like 20.000.000 downloads and can help you a lot debugging containers ecc. After installing it you see the dockericon on the left toolbar.

If you can see directly the errors that occurs in the logs, maybe you can post them partially. So it would be possible to understand. Please tell also something about your Frontendapp architecture, (react-app, angular). There are some frameworks that need to be startet on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 or they dont work.
````

Comment: Hi Ralle Mc Black, thank you for your answer!

I don't have any messages in the browser development console. I had to change few things on the code otherwise i get errors during compilation `RUN apt update -y && app install curl -y` to `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install curl -y`. I've also checked if any port use in dockerfile/dockercompse are used by Windows, none of them are used by Windows! When i launch `docker-compose up -d`  all seems to go well but when i check the logs on docker-desktop for the container 'app' i got errors but i can't past them here it's too long!

Comment: I will put an update in my answer. @Albius

Comment: I followed your steps but i still can't access my index.html in the web app

Comment: its been a while wonder if you found a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you are trying to access on port 80. To do that, you have to map your container port 4200 to 80 in yaml file 80:4200 instead of 4200:4200.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: You can map a port to any port avialable on your host. The link you posted is just an example. 4200:4200 is totally correct.

Comment: it seems he would like to call his website on 80.

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeau not necessary on 80, 4200 or any other port available, it's just to test, anyway as i was not really sure port 80 was available i tested with 4400:4200. When i test under Windows `netstat -aon | findstr :4400` there's no result so it's free, then i run docker-compose, once done i checked with `netstat -aon | findstr :4400` and get few results so port is attributed but i still can't access my web app

Comment: ok i thought with the curl you've done.

Comment: How did you configure the website to call the api?

Comment: With the curl on 4200 and 4200:4200 in your docker-compose file, you got the index.html.

Comment: Have tried localhost:4200 in your browser with your first docker-compose file (4200:4200)?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux yes and i don't get any page on the browser

Comment: Could you open your browser in debug mode and check the calls ?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux Hi, sorry i had a lot of stuff to do recently, didn't had the time to answer you ! I've opened the console, go to Network, try to access the container but nothing, i have no errors or messages in the console